# Error using the gsub function

Tags: r, gsub

I have the following piece of code.

```
library(dplyr)

options(dplyr.width = Inf)

fun <- function(col){

  x <- sapply(col, function(x){gsub(x, '\\\\*', col)}); 

  diag(x) <- NA; 

  apply(x, 1, function(x){x[which.min(nchar(x))]})

}

op <- ird_dupfil %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Textfield = fun(Textfield))
```

I receive the following error while I run this:

> Error: invalid regular expression 'received no response from client
>
> closing request
>
> reason 'Invalid use of repetition operators'

Someone pls guide me in solving this error

Comment: Could you please provide sample input (i.e. short sample of what kind of data you have) and desired output? Maybe it's just me, but it's fairly hard to figure out the problem in code without associating it with application of this given function.

Comment: Your first step of debugging should be to test your function outside of dplyr.